# Find records that have children records that match all entries in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def DogOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :breeds, :through => dogs

  def self.with_breeds(breeds)
    # returns a list of DogOwner records who own all breeds in the list

    # ex: DogOwner.with_breeds("Dalmation","Poodle")
    # or it could be DogOwner.with_breed_ids(1,3) which would only require
    # a join down to the dogs table - I could live with that.

    # do i need to hand generate SQL with n levels of subselects?
    # or is there something in ActiveRecord that handles this magically?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way using a list of child ids:

```
DogOwner.all(:joins => :dogs, 
             :conditions => "dogs.breed_id in (#{list_of_breeds})", 
             :group => 'dog_owners.id', 
             :having => "count(*) = #{list_of_breeds.size}")
```

Credit: [Ethan Vizitei's Blog Post](http://codeclimber.blogspot.com/2009/05/joins-and-namedscopes-in-activerecord.html) inspired the solution.

Comment: @ryw, watch out for sql injections there ... sometimes I think certain things are just easier in pure SQL

Comment: Good point Sam - in my real use case the list is all generated from system data, no user input - and not as fun of a domain :)